# Using Different RAM brands, sizes and speeds

Tags: memory, performance, dell-xps, memorystick, xps

I have just purchased a Dell XPS desktop. It has four slots for RAM. Two slots already have 8 GB sticks of Dell DDR5 UDIMM 4400 MHz RAM. I have two sticks of Crucial 16 GB DDR5 UDIMM 4800 MHz. I've been reading that for optimal performance you shouldn't mix brands, sizes and speeds, but I'm not clear on if this refers to all four slots or just the slots in pairs. Would there be an degradation in performance if two slots have the same brand, size and speed and the other two slots have a different brand, size and speed? Would it be best to just remove the 8 GB sticks and use the two 16 GB sticks until I can get the same type of RAM to fill the remaining slots at a later time? Or can I use all four slots in the aforementioned configuration without concern?

Comment: They're similar enough that all four might work together. However, I believe the effective speed will be that of the slowest, i.e., the Dell 4.4 GHz. That said, a 10% difference, if you were to replace the old pair, would likely not be noticeable. Why not test? Do a RAM benchmark test before adding the new sticks, and again after.

Answer (score 2):

As you already have two sticks of Crucial 16 GB DDR5 UDIMM 4800 MHz, the easy answer is to make sure the "new" desktop works with the supplied 8 GB RAM and then replace the two 8 GB sticks with the 16 GB sticks and see if it still works.

Then pop in the old RAM sticks with the new ones and if all the timing specifications of differing components work together in the combination of components that you have then it might work, but the /hassle/ of setting the BIOS timings manually if required (if they are even available to be adjusted) could make it easier to just go with what is already known to work. Or it *could* work with no further setup.

(Remember that if the computer isn't actually using the RAM space then it is wasting electricity on the space that isn't in use, so 64 GB RAM could be wasting 48 GB of components' worth of electricity bill for nothing.)

That's based on you having found that 16 GB of RAM is not enough *and* taking into account the centuries-old principle of...

**"If it ain't broke, don't fix it."**

Comment: You make a good point. I'm just adding RAM because I have it, not necessarily because I need it. I'll just use the 32 GBs of Crucial if it works as it's faster and I can definitely use more than 16 at this point with my current work load. I appreciate the advice!